# Build xy+xz+yz using NAND port

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

for an homework I have to write `xy+xz+yz` using only NANDS port.
I will use the notation NAND(x,y) - or other types of bracket to make things clearer -, below my attempt and then an explanation for every step. I'd like to know if i'm doing this right and if there are better ways to do it.

**My Solution**

```
NAND[NAND(NAND(NAND(x,y),NAND(x,z)),NAND(NAND(x,y),NAND(x,z))),NAND(NAND(NAND(y,z),NAND(y,z)),NAND(NAND(y,z),NAND(y,z))))]`
```

I know this looks really impossible to read and keep track of. I'm sorry, didn't know how to make this more beautiful. Hope my explanation will clarify things.

I divided `xy+xz+yz` in two groups: `xy+xz` and `yz`

**First Group:**

`xy+xz = NAND(NAND(x,y),NAND(xz)) = NOT[NOT(xy)*NOT(xz)] = xy+xz`

**Second Group:**

`yz = NAND(NAND(y,z),NAND(y,z)) = NOT(NOT(yz)*NOT(yz)) = yz (since yz+yz = yz)`

Now I have to combine the first group with the second, for readibility I'll call the first group (in NAND as *g1*) and the second *g2*;

`g1+g2= NAND[NAND(g1,g1),NAND(g2,g2)] = NOT[NOT(g1)*NOT(g2)] = g1+g2`

So at the end:

`xy+xz+yz= NAND[NAND(NAND(NAND(x,y),NAND(x,z)),NAND(NAND(x,y),NAND(x,z))),NAND(NAND(NAND(y,z),NAND(y,z)),NAND(NAND(y,z),NAND(y,z))))]`

Is my reasoning right? There's a more easy way?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct (although you have some missing punctuation -- a couple commas and a parenthesis).  You can confirm by generating a truth table of all possible outputs as so.  I wrote a few lines of C code to confirm.  As for your second question to whether there is an easier way, I don't know.  Maybe someone else can help out.

```
x   y   z   xy+xz+yz     nands
------------------------------
0   0   0      0           0
0   0   1      0           0
0   1   0      0           0
0   1   1      1           1
1   0   0      0           0
1   0   1      1           1
1   1   0      1           1
1   1   1      1           1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help (and sorry about the typos). I didn't thought about verifying myself formally using a truth table but writing snippets to do that sounds a great idea. PS: typos fixed